# Fill empty list in array column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to fill the empty list in my dataframe array column using some string

```
|  array      |
|-------------|
|   []        |
|['pos','neg']|
|   []        |
```

I want to replace empty list with string value

```
|  array      |
|-------------|
|['neg']      |
|['pos','neg']|
|['neg']      |
```

Comment: `df['array'] = df['array'].apply(lambda x: x if x else ['neg'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['array'].str.len().eq(0)
df.loc[m, 'array'] = [['neg']]*m.sum()
```

Or with a loop:

```
df['array'] = [x if x else ['neg'] for x in df['array']]

# slower variant
# df['array'] = df['array'].apply(lambda x: x if x else ['neg'])
```

output:

```
        array
0       [neg]
1  [pos, neg]
2       [neg]
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'array': [[], ['pos', 'neg'], []]})
```